# NHibernate and Structure Map

Tags: nhibernate, structuremap

So I really like working with [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) but always used Spring.Net with it.

I recently came across [StructureMap by Jeremy Miller](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) and really like it better than Spring.Net.  On his StructureMap site he promises an example on how to use NHibernate and StructureMap together.  Unfortunately he has not had time to do it (or I can't find it).

So does anyone have an example on how to handle the NHibernate Session with StructureMap?

Comment: feel like bumping this, i've been waiting for that example also

Comment: Linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383440/using-fluent-nhibernate-with-structuremap-or-any-iocc

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So, I apologize that we did not get the NHibernate with StructureMap example done earlier. Eventually, I would like to publish it in the StructureMap documentation, but I need some feedback first.  You can see the full example on my blog:

http://trason.net/journal/2009/10/7/bootstrapping-nhibernate-with-structuremap.html

That being said, I can hit the highlights here.  There is an NHibernateRegistry that makes available four things: an NHibernate.Configuration (as a Singleton), an ISessionFactory (as a Singleton), an ISession (scoped Hybrid (HttpContext if available, falling back to Thread local storage)), and a very simple IUnitOfWork.  Also, there is an HttpModule to manage the UnitOfWork per web request.

Here is the code for the NHibernateRegistry:

```
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Driver;
using NHibernateBootstrap.Core.Domain;
using StructureMap.Attributes;
using StructureMap.Configuration.DSL;
using Environment=NHibernate.Cfg.Environment;

namespace NHibernateBootstrap.Core.Persistence
{
    public class NHibernateRegistry : Registry
    {
        public NHibernateRegistry()
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration()
                .SetProperty(Environment.ReleaseConnections, "on_close")
                .SetProperty(Environment.Dialect, typeof(SQLiteDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(SQLite20Driver).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                .SetProperty(Environment.ConnectionString, "data source=bootstrap.sqlite;Version=3")
                .SetProperty(Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, typeof(ProxyFactoryFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName)
                .AddAssembly(typeof(Blog).Assembly);

            var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

            ForRequestedType<Configuration>().AsSingletons().TheDefault.IsThis(cfg);

            ForRequestedType<ISessionFactory>().AsSingletons()
                .TheDefault.IsThis(sessionFactory);

            ForRequestedType<ISession>().CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid)
                .TheDefault.Is.ConstructedBy(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());

            ForRequestedType<IUnitOfWork>().CacheBy(InstanceScope.Hybrid)
                .TheDefaultIsConcreteType<UnitOfWork>();

                ForRequestedType<IDatabaseBuilder>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<DatabaseBuilder>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the Unit of Work:

```
using System;
using NHibernate;

namespace NHibernateBootstrap.Core.Persistence
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        ISession CurrentSession { get; }
        void Commit();  
    }
}

using NHibernate;

namespace NHibernateBootstrap.Core.Persistence
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private readonly ITransaction _transaction;

        public UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
        {
            _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
            CurrentSession = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            _transaction = CurrentSession.BeginTransaction();
        }

        public ISession CurrentSession { get; private set;}

        public void Dispose()
        {
            CurrentSession.Close();
            CurrentSession = null;
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            _transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the NHibernateModule for web applications:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using NHibernateBootstrap.Core.Persistence;
using StructureMap;

namespace NHibernateBootstrap.Web
{
    public class NHibernateModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += ContextBeginRequest;
            context.EndRequest += ContextEndRequest;
        }

        private void ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _unitOfWork = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();

        }

        private void ContextEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _unitOfWork.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But aren't you blocking the database for a whole request with this? I mean you begin transaction after request starts, and commit it after it's ended.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help: http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2007/02/05/inject-di-container-into-domain-objects-with-nhibernate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- Edit here:  I posted this comment before wbinford's answer was posted.  I still think using NCommon is good, but his answer above is a little cleaner and does not require the use of another third party tool.

I really didn't get the answers I was looking for but I found a nice framework called [NCommon](http://ncommon.codeplex.com/).  It implements the unit of work pattern along with the repository pattern with NHibernate, LinqToSql or the Entity Framework.  It also handled the NHibernate ISession as well as configuration for NHibernate.  I used the tool with StructureMap and NHibernate.  I did have to get the service adapter for StructureMap, but once set up it works rather nicely.

Comment: Hi dionysus55,

Im trying to us NCommon with structure map and im totally lost. Do you have any sample code showing how to do this?

Comment: Sorry I have nothing I can release.  If you look at wbinford's answer he sums up the process.  The url he points to helps as well.