# Rhino Commons Nhibernate Module w/ Structuremap

Tags: nhibernate, structuremap, rhino-commons

Has anyone gotten the NH session management bits from RhinoCommons to work with Structure Map? We already use SM and do not want a dependency on Windsor.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar iwth Rhino Commons and the value it delivers. If it only gives you NH session management I believe there are other ways to get that job done.

[Weston Binford](http://trason.net/journal/2009/10/7/bootstrapping-nhibernate-with-structuremap.html) has a series of posts on using NHibernate with StructureMap.

[Jeremy Miller](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2010/01/06/how-dovetail-uses-structuremap-with-nhibernate.aspx) has a post on integrating StructureMap and NHibernate.

A StackOverflow topic on wiring up [NHibernate and Structure Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122339/nhibernate-and-structure-map).