# ASP.NET MVC 2 , Nhibernate and transaction across layers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, unit-of-work

I am creating a solution in ASP.NET MVC 2, NHibernate and DDD. I am using a semi CQRS type Model.

ASP.NET Controller send validated messaged to Service Layer which updates state of an Domain object. 
I have my Domain  Dispatch "Events" and these are then caught by "Event Handlers" who act on them. Each of these Event Handler  have access to Repository Layer  and can commit an Domain Object State.

Event Handlers also insert  records directly into reporting based tables  using a (non NHibernate ) Repository. Event Handlers may also do non database related operations like sending emails.

Event Handler can also change state of an  object thereby creating new set of events.

How can I assure  that all  database operation that occur during a single asp.net Request  are inside a single Transaction.
I have been reading some blogs ( like [Kevin Williams](http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/2010/04/06/setting-up-asp-net-mvc-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-structuremap/) , [Matt Wrock](http://mattwrock.com/post/2010/12/26/Getting-TransactionScope-to-play-nice-with-NHibernate.aspx) and [Davy Brion](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/12/using-nhibernate-in-your-service-layer/)) and have got information on how to start a Session object in Begin and End Request ( Again I will be using Structure Map here) but not sure how the transaction is maintained.  This was compounded by the fact that start and end Requests may be called on different threads.

My Repository  Class takes NHibernate  ISession  in its Parameter.  If I create ISession as Hybrid Scope ( StructureMap) will that ensure that during a request  ISession parameter that is passed by StructrueMap  remain same.

Please advise and also let me know if my question is not clear.

Thank you,

Mar

The Mar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider implementing the `Unit Of Work pattern` for each web request. The unit of work creates an NHibernate session and also handles transactions. There are several implementations that you can find on the web such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122339/nhibernate-and-structure-map) and [this](http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/unit-of-work-part-1/).

Comment: I accepted this answer because these two links gave good information to start working on my  UoW

Answer (score 0):

in addition to WorldIsRound's answer- you haven't specified in your description where transactions are created and commited (from your explanation i'm assuming it should be somewhere in the Service layer).
I konw that there are tools that'll manage your sessions, and maybe your transactions, for you, but in my opinion, you want to explicitly control your transactions.
I use UOW pattern in my projects as well, to create a Session object in the Begin_Request event, and then I use that object to create transactions when I need them.
Again, that's just my opinion, but I think you should have complete control over opening and closing your transactions.
Good luck

Comment: Thank you. I want the transactions to be created at  start of the request and commit at end request. I am also looking at having it  in start of an action execution and commit at end of Action Execution. This way  I dont need to start transaction for query based database calls.